# Having trouble understanding Methods and Professor Instruction

Tags: java, methods

OK my professor has specified

> "Your ship's refuel method should take an integer amount and
>   not return anything.  When a ship is asked to refuel, its current fuel
>   level is increased by the additional fuel amount specified and it
>   reports that it was refueled: "Enterprise added 5 to its fuel
>   reserves."  However, if a ship is asked to refuel with an additional
>   fuel amount less than one, the ship's fuel level remains unchanged and
>   it reports why it wasn't refueled: "Enterprise cannot refuel with -5
>   fuel."

This is what I have

```
    public refuel(int Fuels)
    {
        if(Fuels < 1)
        {
            Fuels = fuel;
            "Challenger cannot refuel with " + fuel + " fuel.";
        }
        else
        {
            fuel += Fuels; 
//return (name + "added " + Fuels + " to its fuel reserves");
        }
    }
```

Compile Error when I run this code:

> invalid method declaration; return type required  public refuel(int
>   Fuels)

When i input

```
public String refuel(int Fuels)  and insert the return statement, the method it compiles.
```

Comment: use `public void`

Comment: And fix the other syntax errors as well.

Comment: Your method should be `public void refuel(int Fuels)`. You are missing return type in your method signature.

Comment: Why is public void used? and Thanks for the Help it complies fine after that.

Comment: The error message clearly says `return type required`. It works when you do `public String refuel(...` because `String` is the return type. Since you don't want to return anything, you should use `void`.

Comment: Ahh k, I see now. Thanks guys!

Comment: This how you defines method in Java. You need to specify return type for the method otherwise you will get same compilation error. You can have any return type which you think your method should return. If you wnat to return a message, which you have commented, then your return type would be String. If you want to retun recalculated fuel amount then return type should be int and if you do not want your method to return anything then use void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For methods/functions you want to return nothing from, you should use the void return type. As for the instructions, your professor wants you to add the fuel when necessary and  output the proper message to the user. Your code is basically correct with a few minor syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your method doesn't have a return type.
As per your requirement,add void between public and refuel.

Why void?
When the method doesn't return anything,we make use of void i.e no return statement required.

In case you need to return other data types,then add int,float,char etc.. accordingly.